# ODBC connection report for Crystal Report not working on other machines

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports, odbc, crystal-reports-xi

**SETUP**

I am currently running on Crystal Report 2011.
I have created a Crystal Report that pulls data from a MySql database. I had to setup an ODBC connection in the Data Source wizard under Admin Tools. I created the report and saved it. I then opened it up in a report view and it worked fine.

**PROBLEM**

When i try to run the report on another computer, it gives "Failed to open a Connection". I setup the ODBC connection on the other computer.

**QUESTION**

Does anyone know how to make it so i can deploy a Crystal Report using MySql tables to other machines?

Comment: Have you configured MySQL so that each of these systems has access to the database. It's done with grant on the server.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus yes, i actually just figured it out. When i create the Crystal Report, i add it by adding it as a DSN. ill post the answer i got. but maybe someone can explain why it has to work that way and not the way that i have been adding every other Crystal Report with MS SQL

Comment: @zach I'm facing the exact same problem, how did you solve yours?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your original question, it sounded like you had trouble accessing a MYSQL db from a different node (server), and my suggestion was to make sure that user and node were entered into MySQL's user table. I happen to use the grant directive to do this.

MySQL's access is user/ip-address based, whereas MS SQL Server is either server login (sa or other users) or Windows domain login based. Although an Microsoft SQL Server expert would call these two login approaches using more correct terminology, these approaches are slightly different than MySQL's approach.

Comment: @octopusgraddus Yeah i made sure that it was setup correctly and it is. The problem is i can't run the report on Crystal Server. I can run it through a computer client (The Report Viewer Pro), but when i try it on the server it won't accept the username and password. any idea why that is?

Comment: Not having all that to reproduce the problem, I don't know why you're having that problem. Sorry.